# Verify if XPATH path is valid without XSD

Tags: java, xpath

I was able to successfully get values from an XML document using XPath, now for a negative scenario wherein the actual path does not exist in the XML structure, such that `path = /Data/XEDA/PrimaryKey`, is returning null. I was thinking that it will return `XMLParseException`. Kindly enlighten me. Thanks in advance

```
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc);
    System.out.println(result);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data BatchOrOnline="O" TotalRec="1">
<ZETA>
    <PrimaryKey>1</PrimaryKey>
    <Co>
        <ForeignKey>3</ForeignKey>
        <tblValuId>CP</tblValuId>
        <tblDescTxt>Test</tblDescTxt>
    </Co>
</ZETA>
```

Comment: Well, what _did_ you get?

Comment: Well, there is a difference between a perfectly valid XPath which just does not match anything (like in your case) and a XPath whose syntax is incorrect (where you indeed get an exception).

Comment: This is how it works... it won't give you an exception unless your xpath is actually invalid. Also SQL query doesn't throw an exception if there is no matching row in the DB.

Comment: @Matthias it returned null without any exception. If that would be the case how will i know if the path is valid or not? or suggest better approach.
Balint Bako Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get an Xpath exception unless your xpath is actually wrong. In your case your Xpath expression "/Data/XEDA/PrimaryKey" is valid. All that it's returning is there is no such node in the xml hence null.

Comment: Yes agree. But is there something that I can do to limit invalid expression where it doesnt comply, say to any of the elements?

Comment: If I understand you right; you want a way to see before running an xpath if the node you looking for exists (which is what you are referring to as “invalid/valid expression”). Without actually running the xpath I know no way of knowing if the expression will find a node. What you can do is write a helper class that can do this check for you. I can post some code if you wish.